# Adding custom image field to Metatags D8?

Tags: 8, meta-tags

I'm using Metatags module on Drupal 8, all text fields seem to be working just fine. I'm trying to set the OpenGraph Image tag from an image field in my content type, called `field_thumbnail`.

Here are the tokens I'm using (I installed tokens contrib module to make sure I was using the correct ones)
[image]

But when I view the tags, it's coming up empty or what seems to be a line break of sorts. See here:

[image]

Anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Looks like a bug: https://www.drupal.org/node/2667850, and that leads to this comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2631408#comment-10941023

Comment: Thanks @mradcliffe, Applying that patch (https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/meta_tags_don_t_filter-2631408-29.patch) did indeed fix this issue.